# Howto initialize a OneWayToSource property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

```
   <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="something" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSomething, 
                              Mode=OneWayToSource, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I want property `IsChecked` to be initialized with `True`.

I can not do it in my ViewModel.

I do not want to do it in my code behind.

I do not know how to do it in XAML but I believe it is the correct place to do so.

Comment: Why you cannot do it in your ViewModel ?

Comment: @Myriam, because ViewModel initialization of the ViewModel property will be overwritten during the view construction with the default value `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the Fallback value of the Binding to True:

```
<dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="something" IsChecked="{Binding IsSomething, 
                              Mode=OneWayToSource, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=True}"/>
```